# .htaccess MOD_rewrite for the entire site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that is under www.domain/store

I want to get rid of store using MOD_rewrite for the entire site.

Is this possible to do with mod_rewrite??

The site is built on Opencart.

I've tried what was suggested below:
I'm getting internal server error so I've looked at Apache error log and below are the errors:

```
[Sun Oct 23 03:02:09 2011] [error] [client 120.144.194.243] File does not exist: /home/favstayc/public_html/404.shtml
[Sun Oct 23 03:02:09 2011] [error] [client 120.144.194.243] File does not exist: /home/favstayc/public_html/favicon.ico
[Sun Oct 23 03:02:09 2011] [error] [client 120.144.194.243] client denied by server configuration: /home/favstayc/public_html/error_log
[Sun Oct 23 03:02:09 2011] [error] [client 120.144.194.243] client denied by server configuration: /home/favstayc/public_html/.htaccess
```

OK I got my answer now. Below is the answer!

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)store
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ store/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, using this pattern everything redirects to `/store/whatever` invisibly for the user. So your user enters `http://example.com/some-product`, and Apache serves the user `http://example.com/store/some-product`.

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^store.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I don't want to have store appearing on the url. Is it possible?

Comment: That's exactly what this rule does. Unless you add a [R], flag it will not redirect the user's browser.

Comment: @hybmg58 Check your Apache error_log to see what the error is. Also see addition of `RewriteCond` above.

Comment: OK I'm getting this error now: This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: @hybmg58 See addition, which checks if the requested item is a real file (i.e., it exists in the `store` directory). If it does, the rewrite doesn't take place so you don't get a loop.